# Object leaving property value after being clicked on

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm practicing HTML and CSS at the moment and making webpage from a PSD-template, it's going good so far, but I'm facing the following problem:

The problem is that border disappears after being clicked on and `:focus` doesn't seem to handle the issue. I need the border to be present until i click on another element, can it be done with CSS? If yes (and that's probably the answer), then how? If it has a JS solution, I'd be glad if you help me with that.

```css
.icons_and_text {
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: Segoe WPN;
  color: #727171;
}

.icon {
  padding: 26px 52px 52px 52px;
  z-index: 2
}

.icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon:active {
  border: 3px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom: white;
}

.icon:focus {
  border: 3px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons_and_text">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="Images/phone_img.png">
    <p>Responsive</p>
      <p>Websites</p>     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creating a snippet and clicking TIDY shows invalid HTML, you cannot wrap P in Ps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div:focus` Won't work by default, unless the div has a `tabindex` attribute.

> The tabindex attribute specifies the tab order of an element (when the "tab" button is used for navigating).

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp).

It also enables focus functionality to the element, so if you want your div to have focusing abilities, just add this attribute: `tabindex="0"`.

```css
.icons_and_text {
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: Segoe WPN;
  color: #727171;
}

.icon {
  padding: 26px 52px 52px 52px;
  z-index: 2
}

.icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon:active {
  border: 3px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom: white;
}

.icon:focus {
  border: 3px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons_and_text">
  <div class="icon" tabindex="0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <p>Responsive
      <p>Websites</p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It also adds an outline when focused, which you may disable using `outline: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

i made with jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icons_and_text').click(function(){
    $('.icon').toggleClass("new");
  })
});
```

```css
  .icons_and_text{
    padding: 0 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family: Segoe WPN;
    color: #727171;
}
.icon{
    padding: 26px 52px 52px 52px;
    z-index: 2
}
.icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icon:active{
    border: 3px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom: white;
}
.icon:focus{
    border: 3px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom: white;
}

.new{
    border: 3px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons_and_text">
   <div class="icon">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/200">
       <p>Responsive <p>Websites</p></p>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```